# android bindService() NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

The following code keeps throwing null pointer exception...

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 Button but;
 Button but2;
 LocalBinder binder;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  but.setOnClickListener(this);
  but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
 }
 
 ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection(){

  @Override
  public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
   Log.d("D1", "connecting");
   binder = (LocalBinder) arg1;
   
  }

  @Override
  public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
   Log.d("D1", "disconnecting");
   
  }
  
 };
 
 public static class ServiceTest extends Service{

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return new LocalBinder();
  }
  
  public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
   public void toast(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hope this works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceTest.LocalBinder.class);
  bindService(i, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bind completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 
 public void binderMethod(View v){
  binder.toast();
 }
}
```

I guess that the reason is that onServiceConnected does not execute, which causes binder to stay null. (The but button binds the service to the activity while but2 executes binder.toast(); - the exception is thrown when but2 is pressed)

Basicly the question is : why doesnt onServiceConnected execute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that intent should lead to service, not binder in service: `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceTest.class);`

Comment: oops, didnt notice i had entered .LocalBinder in there. Thanks!